# Google Maps on IPhone won't zoom

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have an iPhone app that loads the following URL:

http://maps.google.com?q=Apple Stores&ll=37.331689,-122.030731&z=3

As expected, the google maps app loads on the phone, but zooms to the entire US.  It does not appear to be respecting the z= parameter, or at least, not allowing a zoom level that shows stores in the area.

Comment: Have you considered using MapKit as opposed to loading the map in a UIWebView?  I have found it is really powerful and pretty straightforward to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

z=3 zooms to the country level. z=1 zooms to the "world" level. Larger numbers increase the zoom. Try something like z=8 or 9

[http://maps.google.com?q=Apple+Stores&ll=37.331689,-122.030731&z=9](http://maps.google.com?q=Apple+Stores&ll=37.331689,-122.030731&z=3)

Edit: On second thought, 10 or 11 might be more appropriate. I guess it depends on how close you want the zoom. The maximum is 19

Comment: Tried 20 and the back to 14.  What I am noticing is if the user on the  phone has set the zoom level on the map prior, the z= param does not seem to be reflected.

Comment: Maps on Google Maps have an integer "zoom level" which defines the resolution of the current view. Zoom levels between 0 (the lowest zoom level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) to 21+ (down to individual buildings) are possible within the default roadmap maps view.